# doing joins in filter criteria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have two dataframes like:

```
df1:
   | a | b |
 0 | 0 | 0 | 
 1 | 0 | 1 |
 2 | 1 | 1 |


df2:
   | c | d |
 0 | 0 | 1 |
 1 | 1 | 1 |
 2 | 2 | 1 |
```

how could I select rows from `df2` where `df1[df2['c']]['b'] != 0`.  So in other words, rows from df2 where it's value in `column c` is the index used to check the value in `df1 column b` is not equal to 0.

So one other way to look at it.  I select all the columns from `df2` where `column c` is a foreign key to `df1`, and I don't want their value in `column b` to be equal to 0.

Comment: Is the value in `df['c']` always equal to the index?

Comment: yes, it'll always be a foreign key to an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick. Let me know if you need something else.

```
df1['index1'] = df1.index
df = pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['index1'], right_on=['c'])
df = df[df.b != 0]
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but it will only work if each item in `df2['c']` is equal to that item's index in `df2`.

Comment: also, you can use `left_index=True` instead of creating the left index